# How to prove that certain points lie on the particular sides of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$ let $D,E,F$ be points on its sides such that

- $A$ and $D$ divide the perimeter of triangle into two equal parts
- $B$ and $E$ divide the perimeter of triangle into two equal parts
- $C$ and $F$ divide the perimeter of triangle into two equal parts

Prove that $D,E,F$ lie on $BC$, $AC$ and $AB$ respectively.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality. You only need to show $1$ case (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality). Btw I think you've got $AB$ and $AC$ mixed on the last line.

Comment: The semiperimeter (half the perimeter of the triangle) is always less than every side, but then is also less than the sum of every *pair* of sides. This will tell you that the point dividing the peerimeter in half lies on the side opposite to the vertex , which is the other division point. That is the result.

Comment: (You don't need to know this to solve the problem, but...) Fun fact: The perimeter-bisection points $D$, $E$, $F$ are precisely where the triangle's [excircles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Excircles_and_excenters) meet the corresponding sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $D$ lies on $BC$; $E$ and $F$ follow by symmetry.

The triangle inequality implies that no side occupies more than half of the perimeter. If $D$ was on $AB$, $AD$ would be half the perimeter and thus $AB$ would be *more* than half the perimeter, a contradiction. Similar reasoning applies to $D$ on $AC$, so $D$ is on $BC$.